# How to fadeOut my element when I am scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make nice parallax website, but this is my first time when I am using jQuery, however I have the following problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="section4"><h1 class="text-center">Online Marketing</h1></div>
<div class="section4"><p style="text-align:justify">SOME TEXT IS HERE BUT IT DOES NOT IMPORTANT</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.section4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
}
.is-showing{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px); 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.is-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 
if($(window).scrollTop() > 800){

if (wScroll > $('.section4').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2.2))    { 
    $('.section4').each(function(i){

        setTimeout(function(){

            $('.section4').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
        }, 250 * (i+1));
        })
 }
 }
```

So when I am scrolling down it is work great. It fades in properly, but now I want, when user scroll up, to it disappears. I tried with:

JS :

```
else {
    $('.section4').eq().addClass('is-hide');
    })      

    //$('section4').fadeOut("slow");
}
 /*if (wScroll < $('.section4').offset().top + ($(window).height() - 500)) {
    $('.section4').addClass('is-hide');

 }*/
```

And lot of simular example, but now I don't have idea how to fix it, so if someone can give me advice or some solution I will appreciate it.

Comment: where are you setting wScroll ?

Comment: @Deep sry and thank you I forgot to paste it. Now I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to detect scroll direction,, I would do the following:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
 var isScrollingDown = false;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (lastScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) {
       isScrollingDown = false;
    } else {
       isScrollingDown = true;
    }
    // Do something
});
```

You can use this logic within your code to do as required.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are looking third party solution you can check out [Wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW)

It is great lightweight library that uses animate.css effects on scrolling.